# Manage ValidFrom and ValidTo inside a transaction in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, transactions, temporal-tables

I use temporal table in SQL Server to store some historical data.

According to the doc, all the actions in the transaction will be mark at the same time when first transaction begin. But I'm not happy with this behavior, I need to do 2-3 different jobs and each job must has different timestamp or some logic will fail, it also need to rollback if one job failed.

Example, the result in database is like this

| Column A | ValidFrom |
| --- | --- |
| Result1 | timestamp1 |
| Result2 | timestamp1 |
| Result3 | timestamp1 |

What I need is the result from 3 job will be in different timestamp although 3 job is run in the same transaction.

| Column A | ValidFrom |
| --- | --- |
| Result1 | timestamp1 |
| Result2 | timestamp2 |
| Result3 | timestamp3 |

Is there any way rollback some action in temporal table without running in transaction. Or is there any way to change the system time to make all action not to be the same timestamp?

Currently, I temporary disable transaction when do those jobs. But it too risk if one of job is failed.

Comment: Make 3 separate transactions?...or wrap in a transaction in application code instead of a SQL transaction?

Comment: @J.D. what did you mean by "wrap in a transaction in application code"?

Comment: Is your SQL code called from an application or how is it executed?